# Shell: Remove Additional .csv Extensions Accidentally Added to Every File

Tags: macos, shell

I made a mistake with my shell script path and accidentally ran this shell script on a much larger set of files than the small folder where it was intended:

```
 find . -type f -exec mv '{}' '{}'.csv \;
```

As you can imagine, it added an additional `.csv` to a lot of files regardless of what they were before that: .pdf, .xlsx, .mp3, .zip, .csv, etc. -- whatever it found. A very large, unfortunate mistake.

Is there a way I can reverse this by running similar code to remove the additional .csv from the end of each file? Anything I can do short of reverting to my last backup which is much longer ago than I'd like. Thanks for the help.

--

**EDIT**

I've unfortunately found that some files have more than one .csv on the end (e.g. one file could be `.pdf.csv` and another could be `.mp4.csv.csv.csv`).

Is it possible to write this command to look for a `.` only after the first `.` and file name and delete any additional `.csv`s thereafter? That way if a file was just `.csv` it should leave it as `.csv` and if a file is `.csv.csv` it should change it to `.csv` and if it's `.pdf.csv.csv.csv` it should change it to `.pdf` (for example). Basically, all I want is the first extension and to delete anything following it if that extension is `.csv` or multiple `.csv`s (because some files are in as `.csv.csv.csv.csv`).

**Desired Outcome**

Some shell script that would make all my files change to this:

```
mv ./.downloads/worktable1.csv.csv ./.downloads/worktable1.csv
mv ./.bash_history.csv.csv.csv.csv.csv.csv ./.bash_history
mv ./Application Support/AddressBook/Configuration.plist.csv.csv ./Application Support/AddressBook/Configuration.plist
mv ./Application Support/Google/Chrome/DEFAULT/Bookmarks.csv.csv.csv ./Application Support/Google/Chrome/DEFAULT/Bookmarks
mv ./.dropbox/instance1/host.dbx.csv.csv.csv.csv.csv ./.dropbox/instance1/host.dbx
mv ./.qgis2/python/plugins/processing/tests/data/lines.dbf.csv.csv ./.qgis2/python/plugins/processing/tests/data/lines.dbf
```

Pretty sure that it added multiple `.csv`s to the end because it was supposed to run whenever a folder was activated, though I don't know why some have different numbers of extensions than others. Hopefully we can figure out that pattern, but it seems like the hardest thing will be differentiating between the files that don't have a file extension at all.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this `find` command:

```
find . -name '*.*.csv' -exec bash -c 'echo mv "$1" "${1/.csv*/}"' - '{}' \;
```

to remove all `.csv` extensions from each file.

Once you're satisfied with the output, just remove `echo` before `mv`

Comment: Thanks so much. I think what happened is I believe I changed my path to the folder I wanted but I didn't work, so it ran through the whole system. Do you recommend anything else? Definitely don't want any more unwelcomed surprises. I also don't want to remove .csvs from files that are actually supposed to be .csvs -- but those I think now all look like ".csv.csv". As you can probably tell, very new to attempting to do things through shell script.

Comment: I've tested it on OSX in a separate subfolder with bunch of `.csv` files and it shows output as `mv ./file.csv ./file`

Comment: But what if there are files with just one `.csv`? I don't want to accidentally turn those files into one without an extension.

Comment: In addition to that -- I'm nervous it's still running somehow? When I look at your echo, it looks good but there are some files with three .csvs? And some with two now? The ones at the top of your `echo` have more than the ones at the bottom.

Comment: Here's an example of the top of the `echo` vs the bottom: `mv ./.bash_history.csv.csv.csv.csv.csv.csv.csv.csv ./.bash_history.csv.csv.csv.csv.csv.csv.csv` and `mv ./Application Support/Google/Chrome/Default/Bookmarks.csv.csv.csv ./Application Support/Google/Chrome/Default/Bookmarks.csv.csv`

Comment: Sorry for all the comments but when I run `ps aux | grep sh` I get back a few, but I assume `Ryan           13020   0.1  0.0  2463084   1104 s000  S     6:37PM   0:00.06 -bash` is the one that's doing the harm since it's in `bash` and the rest are things like support and core services and stuff. Thanks again for the help, would love if you had additional suggestions.

Comment: Last one! I think I figured out the pattern regardless of how many times the files got affected for whatever reason. Is it possible to write this command to look for a `.` only after the first `.` and file name and delete any additional `.csv`s thereafter? That way if a file was just `.csv` it should leave it as `.csv` and if a file is `.csv.csv` it should change it to `.csv` and if it's `.pdf.csv.csv.csv` it should change it to `.pdf` (for example). Any suggestions?

Comment: Use `-name '*.*.csv'` to get just files that have .csv after another something with a `.`.   Run it multiple times to deal with files with repeated .csv extensions.

Comment: @ChrisDodd     That could potentially work -- how would you do it in total? Would like to run it with an `echo` first to see so I don't go through any of the problems I had with the original command I ran. Happy to run it multiple times until things work. I suppose that doesn't take care of the files on my computer that didn't have an extension that I accidentally added `.csv` to but I can just do those manually later if this takes care of the rest.

Comment: @anubhava      Thanks. So I would just run that over-and-over until they're all taken care of?

Comment: @anubhava      Thanks -- but what about files like example.mp3.csv?

Comment: @anubhava      I think mildly tweaking your code did it! Now that I'm looking at more `echo` examples, it makes way more sense to delete any instance of `.csv` and then add those back in because of all the unix files that purposefully don't have an extension. So this one: `find . -name '*.*.csv' -exec bash -c 'echo mv "$1" "${1/.csv*/}"' - '{}' \;`